# Using Ruby with Rubymine, or another debugger, is it possible to enter debug mode upon an error condition?

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine

I can't seem to find any information about this.  It either doesn't exist or I am using the wrong search terms...

I understand debugging using breakpoints and other controlled execution modes.  However, what I would like to do is have the debugger open up upon an error condition.  I've had that capability in other IDE's but I don't see it here.

Am I missing something?  Are there options for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need program to stop when exception occurs. You should add an [exception breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/creating-exception-breakpoints.html)

Comment: I think the exception breakpoint is probably what I want.  I tried it quickly yesterday and it didn't work but I need to spend some time on it to really understand it.

Comment: This is the first best answer, though more information follows.  A Rubymine bug is currently preventing this from working for me, however.  See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13985.

Comment: The bug is patched and all is working in current Rubymine versions.

Answer (score 2):

You want to run the script and only open the debugger at a particular point in the code (if it reaches that). I.e. you dont' want to start the script under the debugger, but start it normally. Perhaps there is some complexity about starting the script, that the debugger gets in the way of.

In ruby alone (without RubyMine) this is possible with a few of the debugging gems. My suggestion is pry-debugger. You get the power of pry as well as a working debugger, and you can launch it at any time from within the code, with little preperation.
https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger

```
def some_method
  binding.pry          # Execution will stop here.
  puts 'Hello World'   # Run 'step' or 'next' in the console to move here.
end
```

From within RubyMine, you can't really use this option because you won't have interactive control of the script. You need to use the RubyMine debugger to start the script. But if you can do that, getting to stop exactly where you want it to is pretty easy. Either set a breakpoint on that line, from within RubyMine. Or raise an exception in the code there, and have RubyMine stop on that exception. If your code and dependent libraries aren't already raising and rescuing exceptions internally, then you can just have RubyMine stop on all exceptions, which is easy to do.

Comment: I had my eye on Pry debugger and thought that might be an option.  As above, since I am in Rubymine, I think the exception breakpoint might be it once I have worked through it.

Comment: I see how to set exception breakpoints by editing them and checking the boxes.  But, that is making no difference for me.  Regular breakpoints still work.  But, exceptions do not trigger the debugger.  I just get the standard error screen in the browser showing the debugging information.  The Rubymine debugger is not triggered and shows no more information than "connected" under the variable list.  Is there some gem or setting that I need that supports this?

Comment: I contacted JetBrains and they reported this failure as a bug.  It can be seen at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13985.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use [pry-rescue](https://github.com/conradirwin/pry-rescue)

From the Readme: "

"pry-rescue is an implementation of "break on unhandled exception" for Ruby. Whenever an exception is raised, but not rescued, pry-rescue will automatically open pry for you"